# update a property in object array

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to update a property in object array based on the number of times some other property is present as element in some other array

I have 2 arrays, `array1` and `array2`:

```
var array1 = ["JOHN", "JACK", "JACK"];
var array2 = [
  {count: 9, value: "JACK"},
  {count: 9, value: "JOHN"},
  {count: 2, value: "TEST"}
];
```

Expected output :

```
[
  {count: 7, value: "JACK"}, // count = 9 - 2
  {count: 8, value: "JOHN"}, // count = 9 - 1
  {count: 2, value: "TEST"}
]
```

In `array1`, "JACK" is present twice, so I need to reduce count by 2, similarly "JOHN" is present once and hence its reduced by 1, "TEST" is not present so unchanged.

I tried the following

```
array1.map(item => {
  return array2.find( p => p["value"] === item);
});
```

With this, I am getting the below output,

```
[
  {count: 9, value: "JOHN"},
  {count: 9, value: "JACK"},
  {count: 9, value: "JACK"}
]
```

I am not sure whether it can be achieved using single lambda expression.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result using array [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) methods, assuming you are not allowed to change the original array:

```js
var array1  =  ["JOHN", "JACK", "JACK"];
var array2  = [{count: 9, value: "JACK"}, {count: 9, value: "JOHN"}, {count: 2, value: "TEST"}]
       
var result = array2.map(({value, count}) => ({value, count: count - array1.filter(a=>a===value).length}))
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

- Using `.filter()` check how many time a `value` is present in `array1`
- Then subtract that result from current `array2` count.
- Then just return a new array of objects with the updated count.

Comment: Thanks ! that is exactly what i wanted

Comment: Hi Palash, I am a newbie here. Just wanted to confirm whether I have sucessfully marked this as answer ?

Comment: No problem, but no it is still not showing as the accepted answer. Maybe this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/205255) will help.

Comment: Yes, you are not a newbie anymore :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` and `map`

1. Loop over array1 and create a mapper object with names as key and repetition of names as value
2. Loop over array2 and see if the name is present in mapper subtract respective value from

```js
const array1 = ["JOHN", "JACK", "JACK"];
const array2 = [{count: 9, value: "JACK"},{count: 9, value: "JOHN"},{count: 2, value: "TEST"}]

const mapper = array1.reduce((op, inp) => {
  op[inp] = op[inp] || 0;
  op[inp]++;
  return op;
}, Object.create(null))

let final = array2.map(({count,value}) =>({
    value,
    count: count - (mapper[value] || 0)
}))

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are allowed to change the original array. ALSO assuming we are not talking 10s of thousand entries since I look up the value in the name array each time:

```js
var array1  =  ["JOHN", "JACK", "JACK"];
var array2  = [{count: 9, value: "JACK"},
       {count: 9, value: "JOHN"},
       {count: 2, value: "TEST"}]

array2.forEach(item => item.count -= array1.filter(val => val === item.value).length);

console.log(array2);
```

Less resources:

```js
var array1  =  ["JOHN", "JACK", "JACK"];
var array2  = [{count: 9, value: "JACK"},
       {count: 9, value: "JOHN"},
       {count: 2, value: "TEST"}]

// create lookup table
const names = array1.reduce((arr,cur) => { arr[cur] = (arr[cur]||0) + 1;  return arr;},{})
// subtract if present
array2.forEach(item => item.count -= (names[item.value] || 0));

console.log(array2);
```

Comment: On the cost of time complexity and side effects :)

Comment: How so? Do we care unless we have thousand of entries?

Comment: Yeah, I will not have many entries, at the max 100 in each array

Comment: @CodeManiac Ok, made a mapper too.